# Display image from requests via framebuf

Tags: python, micropython

I've built an HTTP API returning an image (`HTTP GET http://myRaspi/api/latestImage` → returns image with content-type `image/jpeg`).
On my Raspberry Pi Pico, I loading the image with the [`urequests` library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

```py
import network
import urequests

wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(True)
wifi.connect('<<SSID>>', '<<Password>>')

response = urequests.get("http://myRaspi/api/latestImage")
imageBytes = response.content
```

I've attached a Waveshare ePaper display to the Raspi Pico which can be controlled via [this API](https://github.com/waveshareteam/Pico_ePaper_Code/blob/main/python/Pico-ePaper-7.5-B.py) based on [`framebuf`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/framebuf.html).

Drawing primitives works like a charm, but I want to display the retrieved image, so I somehow have to translate between the image's byte array and `framebuf`, but I'm struggling with finding the easiest way. I came up with the following code:

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import network
import urequests

wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(True)
wifi.connect('<<SSID>>', '<<Password>>')

response = urequests.get("http://myRaspi/api/latestImage")
imageBytes = response.content

i = Image.open(BytesIO(imageBytes))

for x in width:
    for y in height:
        pixelValue = i.getpixel([x,y])
        myFrameBuffer.pixel(x, y, pixelValue)
```

...where `myFrameBuffer` would be [Waveshare's `self.imageblack` `FrameBuffer`](https://github.com/waveshareteam/Pico_ePaper_Code/blob/main/python/Pico-ePaper-7.5-B.py#L59).

But so far, this does nothing but failing because Pillow is not supported on MicroPython

Comment: Does that even run? I don't believe there exists a PIL implementation for micropython.

Comment: No it doesn't, sorry, that's what I used to say with my very last sentence. I've updated and hopefully clarified it

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you would need to find (or probably write) a JPEG decoder that runs on Micropython. That's probably a non-starter (unless you're feeling especially motivated).

A much simpler solution is to have the HTTP API running on your raspberry pi return an image that doesn't require further processing. That is, run the PIL code (or whatever) on the Pi, and have the `/latestImage` endpoint return a block of bytes (and a height and width) that you can write directly to the framebuffer.

Maybe your API would return something like:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| width (2 bytes) | height (2 bytes) | image content (width * height bits) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You could read the width and height like this:

```py
import struct
import urequests

...

res = urequests.get("http://myRaspi/api/latestImage")

width = struct.unpack('h', res.raw.read(2))
height = struct.unpack('h', res.raw.read(2))
```

The remainder is just reading bytes from the response and writing the corresponding pixel values to your frame buffer.

Comment: Looks great, thank you for the inspiration! And for writing the pixel values into the frame buffer, I should use `myFrameBuffer.pixel(x, y, pixelValue)`? If you could add a line for this to your snippet as well, it would be awesome and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know what `myFrameBuffer` is and I'm unable to test it locally. This answer already demonstrates how to `read` bytes from the response, so hopefully the process of reading bytes and then writing them to the framebuffer is relatively obvious.